# Why will picture not slot in next to text

Tags: html, css

I want the picture to slot right in with the header and that info sidebar, however it will not go in there even if I change it's dimension to the proper ones. I would recommend copying the code to your own editor because it does not show up well through Stack Overflow.

```css
.featured-more-info {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 1200px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#flavors {
  color: #3c1c64;
}

.featured-header {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 015px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.product-picture2 {
  float: right;

}
```

```html
<div class="featured-products">
        <h2 class="featured-header"><strong>Try our newest creation, the Quarantine Cookie Pack with our most famous
                flavors!</strong></h2>
        <h4 class="featured-more-info">The Quarantine Cookie Pack is made out of our 4 most popular flavors:<span
                id="flavors"><br> Chocolate Chip, <br> Fudge, <br> The Americano Cookie, <br> and The Fudge Americano
                Cookie</span></h4>
        <div class="product-picture2">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQxy.jpg" alt="Picture of the 4 cookies included" style="width: 860px; height: 230px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: is there a reason you need a margin-right of 1200px?  You'd have to have something near 3000px width for the container to allow anything else to stay on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is the `margin-right`. Although not part of the `h4`'s width it does contribute to it's box-size. Because you've not set an explicit width, simply removing property this does nothing. What you have to do is set a width and remove the margin-right:

```css
.featured-more-info {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 300px;
  /* margin-right: 1200px; */
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 384px;
}

#flavors {
  color: #3c1c64;
}

.featured-header {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 015px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.product-picture2 {
  float: right;

}
```

```html
<div class="featured-products">
        <h2 class="featured-header"><strong>Try our newest creation, the Quarantine Cookie Pack with our most famous
                flavors!</strong></h2>
        <h4 class="featured-more-info">The Quarantine Cookie Pack is made out of our 4 most popular flavors:<span
                id="flavors"><br> Chocolate Chip, <br> Fudge, <br> The Americano Cookie, <br> and The Fudge Americano
                Cookie</span></h4>
        <div class="product-picture2">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQxy.jpg" alt="Picture of the 4 cookies included" style="width: 860px; height: 230px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've used fixed px for the width, I recommend using % on both the `h4` and `.product-picture2` `div` - for example 40%/60%? I also recommend using `box-sizing: border-box;` otherwise the widths will be based on the content, then the padding gets added to the outside; otherwise you'd need to use `calc(40% - 20px)` in order to negate the 10px padding left and 10px padding right.

```css
.featured-more-info {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  /* gin-left: 300px; */
  /* margin-right: 1200px; */
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#flavors {
  color: #3c1c64;
}

.featured-header {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 015px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.product-picture2 {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-products">
  <h2 class="featured-header"><strong>Try our newest creation, the Quarantine Cookie Pack with our most famous flavors!</strong></h2>
  <h4 class="featured-more-info">The Quarantine Cookie Pack is made out of our 4 most popular flavors:<span id="flavors"><br> Chocolate Chip, <br> Fudge, <br> The Americano Cookie, <br> and The Fudge Americano Cookie</span></h4>
  <div class="product-picture2">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQxy.jpg" alt="Picture of the 4 cookies included" style="width: 860px; height: 230px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you want it but here is an example using display flex. I changed some of the margins you had to position elements, not really done correctly.

What I do here is I add a container that wrapps your headers. Then I give the parent wrapper display flex, that is about it. Read more about flex, it will benefit you greatly.

```css
.featured-more-info {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#flavors {
  color: #3c1c64;
}

.featured-products {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.featured-header {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.product-picture {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 560px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-products">
  <div class="featured-content">
    <h2 class="featured-header">
      <strong>Try our newest creation, the Quarantine Cookie Pack with our most famous flavors!</strong>
    </h2>

    <h4 class="featured-more-info">The Quarantine Cookie Pack is made out of our 4 most popular flavors:
      <span id="flavors"><br> Chocolate Chip, <br> Fudge, <br> The Americano Cookie, <br> and The Fudge Americano Cookie</span>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Picture of the 4 cookies included" class="product-picture">
</div>
```